I have been trying to solve this Gaussian integral, which comes up during the perturbation theory
This integral which comes up during finding first order correct in energy of a harmonic oscillator,where e^-(x-y)^2 is perturbation term
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-(x^2+y^2)-(x-y)^2) \ dx \ dy$$
(original screenshot)

Expands the exponent or write it as a matrix product. The integral of $e^{-X\cdot A \cdot X}$ where $X$ is a vector (in your case $X=(x,y)$) and $A$ is a matrix (here a 2x2 matrix) is known an can be found on the Wikipedia page of (multidimensional) gaussian integral

additional answers can be found here in Math SE, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2214058/284619

Following the suggestion in the comment, you can write the integral as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2 x^2 - 2 y^2 + 2 x y} dx dy = \int \int e^{-2 (x \ y) \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -.5 \\ -.5 & 1\end{bmatrix} (x \ y)^T} dx dy \ .$$
Choleski decomposition of the symmetric definite matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -.5 \\ -.5 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  1 & -.5 \\ 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{bmatrix}^T \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -.5 \\ 0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \end{bmatrix} = A^T \, A \ ,$$
can suggest the change of variables
$$\begin{cases}
u = x - \frac{1}{2} y\\
v = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} y \\
\end{cases}$$
to rewrite the integral as
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2(u^2 + v^2)} \left| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right| du dv \ ,$$
with the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation being constant and equal to
$$\left| \frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial (u,v)}\right| = \left| A^{-1} \right| \ .$$
The integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-2(u^2 + v^2)} du dv $$
is a "classical" integral that can be evaluated using polar coordinates, see as an example here.
